# Failure to select item to change background remains after switching off the current page

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache

I have a website on which I insert an *select* with option for the user to choose and each of the options picked will result in a change in the page background's color.

Also I have a navigator to move between 2 pages (for example, page with title "Tittle A" and another with the same DOM structure but its title "Title B")

The option includes "iA, iB, iC" items.

The problem is like this,

in page A, if I choose one option, e.g iB to change the background color, then I pick the navigator to select page B, I will still see the selected iB although the background is refreshed into page B.

Anyone any idea please. I believe this is a cached issue but I have no idea how to resolve this with maybe a piece of javascript [jquery] code or means to flush the cache each time the page is refreshed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a cache effect. To solve this problem try to select needle option by js. Something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#your_option_id_for_example_iA').click();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's due to a "feature" in modern browsers that remember you selection/input in input fields. It's called `autocomplete`. To prevent the browser to remember you choice, you need to turn it off. It can be done with HTML or JavaScript/jQuery.

HTML:

```
// For just a specific element
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
// For an entire form
<form autocomplete="off">
```

jQuery:

```
$('input, select').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

You can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion